# Match first two octets of ip and change it from file

Tags: csv, sed, replace, stream, edit

I have a csv file containing all the IPs from a subnet. We will use as example the subnet `192.168.0.0/24`, to have in account that I want to process all the given lines on the csv for all the IPs on the given subnet.

I'm trying to start with a single IP, we will use `192.168.0.1/24`. At the moment I'm using sed but I don't seem to be able to just change the first two octets (`192.168.`) and keep the other two octets using sed.

This is the sed string I'm using at the moment.

```
cat example.csv | sed -r 's/192\.168\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}/10\.32\./g' > outputexample.csv
```

What I'm missing? Should I use other program after sed via pipe?

Thanks for your time and help!

Comment: `sed 's/192\.168\([^,]*,\?\)/10.32\1/g' input_file`

Comment: Why not simply `sed 's/192\.168\./10.32./g'` ?

Comment: both are valid, simplicity is the key, thanks folks!